# Why searching strings is such a struggle in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, elastic-stack

**Intro:** (Feel free to skip it).
I`ve dealt in a casual way with elastic stack almost daily for the last couple of years as the two companies I worked for use it to aggregate logs. The problem is that in neither of those companies we had an "expert" in elastic stack so any time I need to search through logs I am by myself with little help from google.
Usually, I have a trace id field I can search for so I don't have to deal with queries; but when I need to search strings or other things inside other fields everything seems like an overwhelming struggle.
The problem is probably me, but after an insane amount of grind and googling i feel like I am missing something.

**Main Issue:**
We usually have some logging entries with the format: "methodName, inputOfTheMethod" or "methodName, outputOfTheMethod" or "methodName, errorMessage", or we need to find specific ids for people, customers or account numbers like "0042342672101" inside the logs or certain keywords like "Account Opening"

So, I have a couple of objectives I am currently wasting hours every time i have to do some serious debugging:

1. Search for the equivalent of "LIKE %methodName, %" in SQL for the "message" field on kibana.
2. Search for all the entries that have the string "0042342672101" in any position of the "message" field
3. Search for all the entries that have the literal string "Account Opening" in any position of the "message" field. It seems to be specially difficult to search for literal strings with spaces on it.

I did a lot of googling on these issues but i usually end in the official documentation that brings little help outside the generic examples or with similar questions on forums with no answers.
I would really love to solve these specific issues or even deeper insight on how to approach them or why this wouldn`t work and what are the alternatives to achieve this.

Comment: After several years around search engines in general, and Elasticsearch in particular, I came to realize that there's a universal rule governing the interactions of people with those search engines, which is: "The time it takes a person/group to find something is inversely proportional to the time that person/group took to design their mapping and queries". Said differently, if you started dumping your logs/data into ES without thinking too much about how you were going to search for that data and thought that everything would just work magically, then you'll have a hard time finding your data

Comment: Once again worded differently, if you want your searches to be fast and accurate, then you need to spend the time it takes early on to properly analyze and index your data, before indexing all your data with default mappings and hope that ES will do the heavy lifting for you. ES doesn't know what your use case is, so teach him.

Comment: I would never have picked ES in the first place, but it's the infrastructure that it's already in place and I'm clearly not calling the shots here. I'm only trying to understand why is such a struggle when is usually the recommended solution for log aggregation and which is the right approach for these kinds of issues.
I would love to get paid just find the best tech solution for each case and architecture, but unfortunately that's not the case.

Comment: Again, ES being one of "recommended" solutions never meant that it would work out of the box for all your needs and use cases, no real-world solutions would actually qualify to such requirements. Would you dump data in an RDBMS without first properly defining the table schemas? Clearly no, and the same is true for ES and other NoSQL solutions. As for your case, we can probably get you going a bit further if you share relevant parts of your index mapping and some concrete values that you're trying to search on, as well as the concrete queries you've tried so far. Help us help you!

Comment: Google for "structured logging". Doing this right requires changes in how your developers write log messages, and how those log messages are parsed and uploaded to Elasticsearch (or any other search engine). How easy this is to implement depends on the language and logging frameworks that you're using; for example, the main Java logging frameworks provide the "mapped diagnostic context", which can be used to insert common context into every log message.